# Maven multi module project setup with various, different dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-release-plugin, multi-module

Let me just say this first: I am brand new to Maven. That said I searched around but have not found answers to the following question. I found answers to similar questions, just not this scenario. Or maybe I just misunderstood the answers and this can be solved simply wiht a multi module setup.

I'd have the following dependency hierarchy:

```
database
|  |
|  +---core
|      |  |
|      |  +---business 
|      |        |
|      |        +------App1
|      |        |
|      |        +------App2
|      |
|      +---------------App3
|
+----------------------App4
```

I'd like to make it work so that changes only result in new releases of any "upstream" modules/Apps. Is this indeed a simple case of multi-module maven setup or do I need to do something else?

Comment: What do you mean by " that changes only result in new releases of any "upstream" modules/Apps" ? You want that App4 only use release version of all child of business or core ? You want want that releasing one item would procude a brand new release for all objects ?

Comment: A change in database should effect all apps, since all of them depend on it. A change in core should only effect apps 1, 2, and 3 and a change in business should only effect apps 1, and 2. And yes, I'd like it to produce a brand new release of all the apps (based on the logic that I just mentioned). Furthermore, a release of only App4, should only `jar` (this is Java) the database module and the files for App4.

Comment: OK, so you should adjust your hierarchy. I would post another reply in a ... few time !

Comment: What do you mean by "adjust your hierarchy"?

Comment: please, see answer below, in a a few words, I think database should not be at the top of your hierarchy, and if you want that two projects have two differents lifecycle, you can't use them as submodule of a a same project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that releasing one component produce a new release of each project, just use [maven-release-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-release-plugin): http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/.

### Documentation

As per doc, this would :

> - Check that there are no uncommitted changes in the sources
> - Check that there are no SNAPSHOT dependencies
> - Change the version in the POMs from x-SNAPSHOT to a new version (you will be prompted for the versions to use)
> - Transform the SCM information in the POM to include the final destination of the tag
> - Run the project tests against the modified POMs to confirm everything is in working order
> - Commit the modified POMs
> - Tag the code in the SCM with a version name (this will be prompted for)
> - Bump the version in the POMs to a new value y-SNAPSHOT (these values will also be prompted for)
> - Commit the modified POMs

Because of the maven multi module structure, they are linked together, and each project would be bumped into a new release.

In a few words, this will :

- move version 1.0-SNAPSHOT --> 1.1-SNAPSHOT
- tag 1.0
- generate 1.0.jar (ou war or anything else)

### Plugin usage

Assuming that SCM is correctly defined, and repository and distribution management configured, just add these lines

```xml
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      [...]
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <!-- optional, basic format is ${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.${project.type}-->
        <configuration>
          <tagNameFormat>v@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      [...]
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

And call

```
mvn release:prepare
mvn release:perform
```

### Inheritance vs Dependency

You may consider the two differents Maven approches :

- inheritance, that means parent and multi/sub modules
- aggregation, in other words : use of dependencies

In a multi-maven project, all your modules, including parent, share the same lifecycle. Releasing one imply releasing all, and so, releasing just one is a non sense.

In your case, you can't modify app 1 to 3 whithout impacting app 4.
If App 4 depends App 1, obviously App 1 can't depends on App 4 (circular references are not allowed).

So, you want to isolate App4 and App1 to 3 lifecycles, you should not use multi-modules, but just share a parent project, or a hierachy of pom like corporate > main project > sub project (not submodule).
After that, just declare a dependency between App 4 and App 1. (... into app4 pom.xml)

Just another thought : the name of your projects and submodules sounds strange. "Classical" hierarchy is often (considering multi business object domain for a large project):

```
Main Project (sometimes EAR) --> POM 
|-- Business Object / DAO --> POM
|   |-- Domain 1 --> JAR
|   `-- Domain 2 --> JAR
|-- Core (depends on BO)  --> JAR
`-- IHM / Web App (depends on core)  --> WAR
```

So, database is rarely at the top of hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just one thing: in my illustration, database is actually at the bottom of the hierarchy (even though it's physically at the top of the picture). What I intended to illustrate was that the module database is shared by all Apps.

Comment: OK. It's clearer, and I think the answer is still suitable. Does it answer to your question ?